# Find the general solution of the Cauchy-Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have

$$
x^2\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} - 3x\frac{dy}{dx}  +3y = x^2 - 3x + 3 + 3\ln{x}
$$

the general procedure

$$
ax^2\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} + bx\frac{dy}{dx}  + cy = g(x)
$$

taking $x = e^t$

I got the complementary function

$$
Y_c= Ae^t + B*e^{3t}
$$

I got stuck here.

The nonhomogeneous equation is

$$\color{red}{
y''- 4y' + 3y = e^{2t} - 3e^t\\
y''- 4y' + 3y = 3 + 3t}
$$

What I need to do next to complete the general solution?

Comment: i am doing correct for the complementary function. I can not solve the final part which is the trial function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
$$
y(x)=z(\log x),
$$
then
$$
y'(x)=z'(\log x)/x, \,\,\, y'(x)=z''(\log x)/x^2-z'(\log x)/x^2.
$$
Hence
$$
x^2\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} - 3x\frac{dy}{dx}  +3y = x^2 - 3x + 3 + 3\log{x},
$$
becomes
$$
\big(z''(\log x)-z'(\log x)\big)-3z'(\log x)+3z(\log x)=x^2 - 3x + 3 + 3\log{x},
$$
or
$$
z''(x)-4z'(x)+3z(x)=\mathrm{e}^{2x} - 3\mathrm{e}^{x} + 3 + 3x.
$$
General solution of the homogeneous $z''-4z'+3z=0$ is $$z_h=c_1\mathrm{e}^{x}+c_2\mathrm{e}^{3x}.$$
Special solution of the inhomogeneous is of the form
$$
z_i(x)=a+bx+cx\mathrm{e}^x+d\mathrm{e}^{2x},
$$
for suitable $a,b,c,d$.

Hence
$$
y(x)=z(\log x)=\big(a+b\log x+cx\log x+dx^2\big)+\big(c_1x+c_2x^3\big).
$$